# Strict transform of curve is smooth for finite composite of blow-ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, surfaces, blowup

This is an exercise from Beauville's book called "Complex algebraic surfaces". Let $C$ be an irreducible curve on a surface $S$. We want to show that that there is a morphism $\hat{S}\to S$ consisting in a finite number of blow-ups such that the strict transform of $C$ in $\hat{S}$ is smooth. A hint given says to show that blowing up a singular point of $C$ decreases its arithmetic genus.

We could maybe use the elimination of indeterminacy theorem which states that if we have a rational map $\phi :S \dashrightarrow X$ from a surface to a projective variety, then there are $\eta: S'\to S$ a composite of finitely many blowups and $f:S'\to X$ such that $\phi\circ \eta=f$.

However it has no link is smoothness or arithmetic genus (at least a priori).
Do you have an idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a singularity $p \in C \subset S$, and let $f: S' \to S$ be the blow-up of $S$ in $p$. Let $\tilde C \subset S'$ be the strict transform of $C$. Pushing down the structure sheaf of $\tilde C$ you obtain a short exact sequence of sheaves on $S$
$$0 \to \mathcal O_C \to f_* \mathcal O_{\tilde C} \to F \to 0,$$
where $F$ is a skyscraper sheaf supported on $p$.
Using $p_a(C) = 1 - \chi(\mathcal O_C)$, and the fact that the Euler characteristic is additive under short exact sequences, this leads to
$$p_a(\tilde C) = 1 - \chi(\mathcal O_{\tilde C}) \stackrel{(*)}{=} 1 - \chi(f_* \mathcal O_{\tilde C}) = 1 - \chi(\mathcal O_{C}) - \chi(F) = p_a(C) - \dim H^0(F).$$
Equality $(*)$ is true because the restricted map $f: \tilde C  \to C$ is finite, hence affine, which means that $H^i(\tilde C, G) = H^i(C, f_*G)$ for all quasi-coherent sheaves $G$ on $\tilde C$.

Finally it remains to show $\dim H^0(F) > 0$. As $F$ is supported on $p$, this is equivalent to $F \neq 0$ or that $\tilde C \to C$ is not an isomorphism. I guess one should be able to show that using local coordinates?